# Proof verification for $\int f d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ be a measurable space ($\mu (A):=|A|$) and $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $\int f d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$.

Proof: $\int_{\mathbb{N}} f^+(n) \;d\mu(n)$= $\int_{\mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{\{k\}}(n) \;\; f^+(n) \;d\mu(n)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{1}_{\{k\}}(n) \;\; f^+(n) \;d\mu(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^+(k)$

Where I used the monotone convergence theorem and the definition of the integral of elmentar functions.

Analogously for $f^-$ which shows the statement.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You didn't prove anything...

Comment: Hint: as usual start by proving the statement with simple functions and then generalize by approximation

Comment: @Surb I proved that $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f^+ d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^+(k)$ and since the same holds for $f^-$ it follows that $\int_{\mathbb{N}}f d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{N}}f^+d\mu+\int_{\mathbb{N}}f^- d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^+(k)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^-(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$

Comment: @rebo79 starting with simple functions insn't necessary in this simple case

Comment: If you think that your proof is correct, why do you ask the question on MSE ? However, I insist on the fact that you didn't prove anything...

Comment: @Surb So which part is actually wrong? didn't I showed what I said in my comment before?

Comment: as said rebo70, first prove for $f$ simple, then $f$ positive and finally for $f$ measurable.

Comment: @Surb I actually don't need the case for simple functions. I need just the integral definition for simple functions for $\int_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{1}_{k}(n)f^+(n) d\mu(n)=f^+(k) \mu(\{k\})=f^+(k)$. And the part for f measurable I wrote down in the comments

Comment: @JorisWk take a look at this if you want, for more general point mass distributions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395396/define-a-measure-in-the-following-way/3395423#3395423